# Assign integer to reg in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have problems with this Verilog code. Basically, it won't let me do the `Y = 3'di` statement. Basically, I want `Y` to equal `i`. I am pretty sure the problem is the `i`. So, is there a way to do this in Verilog? Also, `W` is an input with 8 bits (in other words, `W[7:0]`).

```
for (i = 7; i >= 0; i = i - 1)
begin
    if(W[i]) Y=3'di;
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of `W` and `Y`?

Comment: input [7:0] W, output reg [2:0] Y

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can select bits using brackets .

```
for (i = 7; i >= 0; i = i - 1)
begin
    if(W[i]) Y = i[2:0];
end
```

But it isn't even necessary if `i` was declared to be an integer.  It will take however many bits fit in `Y` automatically and you only wanted the LSBs.

Answer (score 2):

You might wish to use a `case` statement here:

```
case (1'b1)
  W[0]: Y=3'd0;
  W[1]: Y=3'd1;
  W[2]: Y=3'd2;
  W[3]: Y=3'd3;
  W[4]: Y=3'd4;
  W[5]: Y=3'd5;
  W[6]: Y=3'd6;
  W[7]: Y=3'd7;
  default: Y=3'd0; // to avoid inferring a latch when W==8'd0
endcase
```

This makes the priority more obvious to readers of your code.

Comment: That's just confusing and not scalable. It wouldn't make it through a code review with me.

Comment: I'd be interested to see whatever approach you think is better.  As I said, the `case` approach I used makes the priority obvious to readers, and IMO is far clearer than the `for` loop approaches above, each of which potentially makes multiple assignments to Y, with each successive assignment overriding previous ones.  This is an easy thing to overlook during a casual reading of the code, particularly for less experienced engineers.  Inadvertent use of unsigned variables in loops having exit conditions of `i >= 0` is another common pitfall with this approach.

Comment: As for scalability, this is only a 3-bit priority encoder; design for scalability belongs only in things that may need to scale and only to the detriment of clarity when absolutely necessary, which is not the case here.

Comment: What I find confusing is having a constant in the case statement, and variables as the labels to each case. That just makes my brain flip, and I have to think about what you've done. I'd rather have `if (W[0]) Y=3'd0;` lines, which would then be highest priority last. That order tends to be the rule for a lot of RTL, so I have no problem there. Better than that though is the loop version given by Jeff. It's less reading, simple and can be parametrised so I only ever have to write it once. Yes, it's only 3-bits wide, but you're already 11 lines vs 4. Add one bit and you're up to 19.

Comment: Regardless of whether you personally find `case (1'b1)` confusing it's a common Verilog idiom.  For example, see section 4.3 of http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2005-SNUG-paper_SystemVerilog_unique_and_priority.pdf and section 7 of http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsICU2002_FSMFundamentals.pdf by Stuart Sutherland and Cliff Cummings respectively, both of whom have served on the IEEE's Verilog working groups for many years.

Comment: At my company, we avoid use of loops in synthesizable code because the relationship between such RTL and the resulting circuits is often non-obvious.  Having a dead-simple code base that's extremely unlikely to surprise me post-synthesis is well worth a bit of extra typing.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that its better to use state machines to do "for-loop" routine.
Something like this:

```
module yourthing(clk, W, i, Y)
input clk;
input [7:0] W;
output [2:0] Y;
reg [2:0] i;  

always@(posedge clk) begin  
  if(reset) begin  
   i = 3'd7;
   Y = 3'd0;
  end

  else begin
    case(i)
      3'd7 : begin
               if(W[i]) Y = i;
               i = 3'd6;
             end
      3'd6 : begin
               if(W[i]) Y = i;
               i = 3'd5;
             end
      3'd5 : begin
               if(W[i]) Y = i;
               i = 3'd4;
             end
      3'd4 : begin
               if(W[i]) Y = i;
               i = 3'd3;
             end
      3'd3 : begin
               if(W[i]) Y = i;
               i = 3'd2;
             end
      3'd2 : begin
               if(W[i]) Y = i;
               i = 3'd1;
             end
      3'd1 : begin
               if(W[i]) Y = i;
               i = 3'd0;
             end
      3'd0 : begin
               if(W[i]) Y = i;
               i = 3'd7;
             end
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Not the same thing. This would take multiple clock cycles.